# is it possible to specify a register for a variable when programming in C targeting a MIPS processor?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, mips, cpu-registers

I am programming in C, targeting MIPS and compiling with mips-linux-gnu-gcc (using Ubuntu).

For debugging purposes, I wanted to place a local variable always inside a specific register, let's say $3.

I tried declaring it like this:

```
register word local_var asm ("$3");
```

(`word` is an user-defined type of 32 bits)

It did not work, the var was placed inside another register ($17). My debugging tools are limited, so I need to place this variable in a low index register.

When compiling, I use the following options:

```
mips-linux-gnu-gcc -O1 -fno-toplevel-reorder -S -o <assembly-output_file> <C_source_code> -march=mips32 -mno-explicit-relocs  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-stack-protector -msoft-float
```

Comment: The register only applies [if you use it in inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html). There are also [global register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html) but you probably don't want to use those.

Comment: What debugger will let you look at some registers but not all?

Comment: It probably does let you look at registers but if the compiler is not using the same register all the time, it might be harder to follow.

Comment: You can compile with `-Og` to have the compiler place all variables on the stack.

Comment: Clarification: stark actually I am developing my own processor in a FPGA. It is not MIPS but it is inspired by MIPS, so I compile for MIPS, translate to my own assembly and test it. Instead f a debugger, I use a hardware called signaltap that grabs signals of my choice. Connecting this signaltap to all 32 registers besides all other important signals would make the design harder to fit in the FPGA.

Comment: RISC V has a base ISA, RV32E, which supports only half of the 32 registers, specifically for lower power & small microcontrollers.  If you could compile code for that you'd have fewer registers to deal with?

Comment: Thanks @Jester, I was trying to use the specific register as an argument when "calling" a macro defined with inline asm. Only when I referenced the variable inside the asm block itself, I got what I wanted. I wish I could mark your comment as an answer, but it  is not possible.